# Select Distinct, but including non-distinct time-stamp

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, if several rows have the same value in one column (e.g. `ID`) but each have a different value in a `TIME` column, is it possible to formulate a `SELECT` statement which selects only the single most recent row for each distinct `ID`?

For example, if I have the following table:

```
TIME      ID
---------------
6:45AM    1     
6:00AM    1
2:00PM    2
3:00PM    2
3:30PM    2
7:00AM    3
8:00PM    4
7:30PM    4
```

I desire a `SELECT` statement that returns the following:

```
TIME      ID
---------------
6:45AM    1
3:30PM    2
7:00AM    3
8:00PM    4
```

I can figure out how to return the desired result *except* without the `TIME` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE1
```

But I can't figure out how to have the result to also include the most-recent `TIME` stamp for each distinct `ID`.

Comment: What is the type of the `TIME` field?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Ah, good question. Oracle doesn't have a time datatype.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So then you should fix your query.  But better yet, the OP should fix his data :-)

Comment: Well, maybe it's a datetime alright and the OP only simplified this in the example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for not clarifying, the data type is `DATE`.

Comment: _Column_, not field...

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called aggregation. You want the maximum time per id:

```
select
  max(time), -- maximum time
  id
from mytable
group by id -- per id
order by id;
```

Comment: @user7294900: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, this works, but why can I not order by `time`? Why must you order by what you are also grouping by?

Comment: You can order by whatever you want. Your example result is ordered by ID, so I wrote the query accordingly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't think that is true in Oracle.  I believe that ordering by a column not in the select clause would either throw an error or be non deterministic.  But, I'll upvote you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If I modify my query to order by `time`, I get the following error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`. Ordering by `id` works fine, however.

Comment: You cannot order by `time` because you do not select it, however you can order by `max(time)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry, if that was unclear.